# How to make the letter "K" that denote Krylov space

Tags: characters

I'm trying to denote the letter K that appear in notation Krylov Space[image]

I've already tried to use \mathcal and \kappa but it's not the same.

Comment: if you have a pdf of that (eg google suggested http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~mhg/pub/biksm.pdf) you can list the fonts it uses (just standard computer modern and ams fonts in that case)

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What package are you using?

Comment: For my humble opinion the `K` of your picture is the same of `\mathcal{K}`.

Comment: You are probably doing `\usepackage{mathptmx}`, Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's the standard `\mathcal{K}`.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{K}(r_0;k)=\operatorname{span}\{r_0,Ar_0,\dots,A^kr_0\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess that your document uses `mathptmx`. Do like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{K}(r_0;k)=\operatorname{span}\{r_0,Ar_0,\dots,A^kr_0\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're using `newtx`, the code should be

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{K}(r_0;k)=\operatorname{span}\{r_0,Ar_0,\dots,A^kr_0\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

looks a bit like kappa from `txfonts`, just a bit bigger:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

\[
\text{\scalebox{1.4}{$\kappa$}}(r_0)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why downvote? This seems to be a valid answer!